# Windows Form renders unevenly in designer

Tags: vb.net

I have a Windows Form that, for some reason, has changed in looks. Even though no UI changes have been made, certain controls look smaller and some controls, such as the Text in a GroupBox wraps when the app is run. However, when I run the app on other workstations, it looks fine. I don't understand what would cause this unless there were Microsoft updates. Any ideas?

I have attached 2 screenshots, one in the designer mode and the other in execution mode.
[image: Designer MOde]
[Execution Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMVJu.jpg)

Thanks,

Comment: Display changed to Large Fonts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034

Comment: There are gobs of good articles on MSDN regarding DPI aware apps

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't design your app with a DPI aware state. Try redesigning it in UWP instead of WFP as UWP is automatically DPI aware.

Also the button that disappears on the right side that says finish, try making sure the Button.visible property is not set to false.

Comment: Might not be a WPF app. Also changing app's framework seems drastic to fix some scaling :)

Comment: was just a suggestion :P

Comment: I've never even heard of UWP. I'm using Windows Forms and not WPF. Am I still able to use UWP? If so, do you know of any good tutorials?

Comment: UWP is project type in visual studio, New Projet> Templates> Visual Basic> Windows Universal, as for tuts no i dont know any sorry.

Comment: This is not a WPF app. It is a straight Windows Forms app. This particular situation has turned critical as the app is in the UAT phase at the moment. I have had some requests to make some changes on the Form. When I make these changes and execute the program, the Form shows up as it looks in Designer Mode (which is the problem. See first post screenshots). So now, I can't even make changes to the physical form. I don't know what to do. As a test, I displayed the Windows Size when I ran the app and the size was the same as what it shows in Design Mode yet the form does not look right. HELP!!!!